# Замена передачи this

Tags: c#

```
class BaseClass
{
    public void Create()
    {
        ChildClass child = new ChildClass(this);
    }

    class ChildClass
    {
        private BaseClass _baseClass;

        public ChildClass(BaseClass baseClass)
        {
            _baseClass = baseClass;
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли получить `BaseClass` в `ChildClass` без передачи его в конструктор?

Comment: Зависит от того, что есть `this`. Если это какой-то глобальный объект, то можно и напрямую обратиться. Но в общем случае - никак. Иначе не было бы смысла вообще в подобных передачах. Короче говоря, не хватает деталей. Нужен [mcve].

Comment: @älёxölüt расширил пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли получить BaseClass в ChildClass без передачи его в
>   конструктор?

Нет нельзя.

Если и есть какие-то хаки, то они убивают производительность.

Answer (score 1):

Вы, вероятно, исходите из соображений, что объект вложенного класса не может существовать без объекта объемлющего. Но в общем случае это не так. Например, можно передать `null` в конструктор `ChildClass`, объект вложенного класса при этом создастся, но экземпляра объемлющего класса для него не предоставлено.

Можно, я думаю, через рефлексию получить название объемлющего класса внутри вложенного. Но вам же нужен не класс, а именно его экземпляр. А подобного рода отношению как раз и задаются вашим (пользовательским) кодом, а не какой-то встроенной архитерктурной особенностью фреймворка.

Таким образом, без явной передачи экземпляра в общем случае не обойтись.